# design a strange data structure, is it possible?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays, amortized-analysis

I need a FIFO QUEUE that can do Insert and Remove from Queue in amortized $O(1)$ but extract min in $O(log n)$. is it possible?

When just find min is important (not removing) there is lots of $O(1)$ solution for all operation.

Update: All given times is amortized cost.

Comment: I am unsettled reading `FIFO` (extract oldest) *and* `extract min` (priority queue).

Comment: (Are you just handling *values* or *somethings* with *keys* (are all *42* exchangeable)?)

Comment: so amortized of PQ is O(log n) for extract min... @greybeard but how whole structure works ?!

Comment: @greybeard now integers only...but I need like a FIFO Queue works for anything...

Comment: I think you can use some kind of combination of DS... maintain queue, maintain PQ (consisting of key-value pairs), maintain list of necessary removals (hashmap or such). O(logN) amortised overall.

Comment: If extract-min desires amortised (rather than worst-case) O(logn) it can be done by doing extract-min and remove from queue operations lazily.

Comment: the proposed solution is very complex, is there any simple solution here? what about your PQ and FIFO? @greybeard

Comment: (Did you notice that that is what shgr1092 spells out in [his answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/132990/19966)?) I'd be *very* surprised if the was a simpler solution - or one demanding less resources unless the problem was restricted some, like *items inserted will never be* $min$ *right away*. I think this question would benefit from an itemised list of the operations required.

Comment: @greybeard is it this the best solution ( O(1) for insert and remove and O(log n) when extract min instead of find min? (i.e O(1) in tree operation when we use find min)

Comment: If there was a faster amortised *extract min*, you had a *sort by key comparison* "faster than $O(n\log n)$".

Comment: very nice tips. please add a bit more details on it? very nice. please. @greybeard

Comment: would you please tell a bit more for you logic? why we can think like this never can be lower than Log n (i know there is lower bound for comparison sorting) @greybeard

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote four data structure: $Q$, $PQ$, $R_Q$, and $R_{PQ}$. $Q$ is a FIFO queue. $PQ$ is a priority queue implemented using a Fibonacci heap. $R_Q$ and $R_{PQ}$ are hash-sets. $R_Q$ stores elements that have been removed from the queue but not removed from the priority-queue yet; $R_{PQ}$ stores elements that have been removed from the priority-queue but not the queue yet.

Our operations are `insert`, `delete`, and `extract-min`. For insert, we insert the element into $Q$ and $PQ$.

We implement `delete` and `extract-min` lazily. For `delete`, let `x=Q.front()`.  If $x$ exists within $R_{PQ}$, that means it has been removed from the priority-queue already. We pop $x$ and remove $x$ from $R_{PQ}$. Then, we set `x=Q.front()` and try again. If $x$ is not within $R_{PQ}$, then this is the element we should remove. We pop $x$ and insert it into $R_Q$.

For `extract-min`, we essentially do the reverse. We take `x=PQ.top()` until $x$ does not exist within $R_Q$, and when it does we pop $x$ and insert it into $R_{PQ}$.

Time complexity for `insert`: $O(1)$ (since we are using Fibonacci heap)

Time complexity for `delete`: amortized $O(1)$ (hash-sets work in amortized constant, and all our operations are either the deletion or lazy extract-min deletions.)

Time complexity for `extract-min`: amortized $O(logn)$ (hash-sets work in amortized constant, all our operations are either the deletion or lazy extract-min deletions, but logn factor due to PQ)

**Update** Code (C++):

```
struct strange_ds{
    queue<int> q;
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    unordered_set<int> rq, rpq;
    
    void insert(int x){
        pq.push(x); q.push(x);
    }
    
    void delete_ele(){
        while(true){
            int t = q.front();
            if(rpq.count(t)){ //already removed from pq
                q.pop();
                rpq.erase(t);
                continue;
            }
            q.pop();
            rq.insert(t);
            return;
        }
    }
    
    int extract_min(){
        while(true){
            int t = pq.top();
            if(rq.count(t)){ //already remove from q
                pq.pop();
                rq.erase(t);
                continue;
            }
            pq.pop();
            rpq.insert(t);
            return t;
        }
    }
};
```

Note that the code uses a standard C++ priority queue, which is *not* a Fibonacci heap, but this can be straight-swapped in. Also, the code assumes that element values are unique, but this can be accounted for in the case that they are not (by associating elements with unique IDs).

Comment: really it's strange for me. especially proof of working this structure? any hint?

Comment: @LisaBerry insert is obvious. For delete just notice that that all lazy extract-min are elements that were deleted in previous extract-min updates (and that each element done in an extract-min will only be iterated through for delete once). So total cost across all is O(#deletions + #extract min), and average is O(1). Symmetrically, for extract-min, total cost is O(logn(#deletions + #extract min)); O(logn) on average.

Comment: would you please tell a bit more on "lazy"

Comment: @LisaBerry The point is when we run extract-min, we only update PQ. Then we note down that we need to update Q "when it is needed" (ie when that element goes to the front of Q). And symmetrically we do the same for delete. So this is a type of lazy update.